# Error on creating foreign key relationship between non-primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have two table

```
CREATE TABLE `abc` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ref_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `ref_id_UNIQUE` (`ref_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `xyz` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ref_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ref_id_UNIQUE` (`ref_id`)
 )
```

I want to make foreign key relation ship between xyz's ref_id and abc's ref_id .But Mysql gives error 1215.

Comment: What is your syntax when you are trying to create the FK?

Comment: @Cid I stand corrected; I always thought they had to be an exact match. thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

You should make the foreign key relationships to the *primary keys*.  I know that MySQL allows foreign key relationships to anything with an index.  But the correct practice is to use primary keys.

So declare the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `xyz` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  abc_id int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ref_id_UNIQUE` (`abc_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_xyz_abc FOREIGN KEY (abc_id) REFERENCES abc(id)
);
```

If you want the `ref_id` for an `xyz` row, then use `JOIN` to get the information.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but this answer is not answering a question. It should be a comment, since you are criticizing (in a justified manner) the way op is writing code. To answer the question you will need to explain what can cause errors when a foreign key is attempted to be created. Hint: the tables already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Gordon Linoff's answer, his suggestion makes sense, even though it does not answer the question. So what can cause an error when you intend to create a `foreign key` relationship? The obvious possibility is syntax error and typo, so you will need to check against those and fix any such problems.

Another possibility is that you have inconsistency, that is, you try to create a `foreign key` constraint in one of your `table`s, but not all the values have exact matches. So, assuming that you have `Foo` and `Bar` table and you intend `Foo.lorem` to be a `foreign key` referencing `Bar.ipsum`, then you will need to ensure that all the values you have for `Foo.lorem` has a `Bar.ipsum` pair with the exact same values (except `null`). If that's not true, then your `foreign key` constraint will not be successfully created. Find such inconsistencies:

```
select distinct Foo.lorem
from Foo
where not (Foo.lorem is null) and
not exists (select 1 from Bar where Foo.lorem = Bar.ipsum);
```

Read the lines carefully and make sure you fix any such `Foo.lorem` values.